# ASP.NET Page directive causing errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I have a page that is exhibiting the strangest behavior.  When building/debugging my project I will sometimes receive build errors pointing to my page directive.

If I insert an additional space between any two attributes in the directive, the error goes away and the build succeeds.

**Page Directive:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" EnableSessionState="true" CodeBehind="myPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="com.mycompany.UserControls.myPage" %>
```

**Resulting Errors:**

```
Keyword, identifier, or string expected after verbatim specifier: @ C:\mypath\myPage.aspx   1   1   myProjectName

A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods   C:\mypath\myPage.aspx   1   1   myProjectName
```

To reiterate, for example, adding an additional space between `Page` and `Language="C#"` temporarily clears the errors. I will see a 100% success rate on the next build, but the error will eventually reappear.  I can often force the error by closing the editor that is showing the `myPage.aspx` and building/rebuilding my project.

*Note:* This behavior was present in Visual Studio 2008, and still remains after a switch to Visual Studio 2010.

**Edit:** Corrected typo where `@` was omitted from page directive in question.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you eventually find the problem? Experiencing the same issue, can't build the project if I have the page open, but if I close it everything compiles fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you missing the @ symbol between the opening <% and the Page keyword?
You have

```
<% Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" EnableSessionState="true" CodeBehind="myPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="com.mycompany.UserControls.myPage" %>
```

and it should be

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" EnableSessionState="true" CodeBehind="myPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="com.mycompany.UserControls.myPage" %>
```

Comment: +1, as you are correct. Unfortunately it's just a typo as I'm copying from an air-gapped system.  Issue remains.

Comment: Is this a Website project or a Web Application project? I've seen a similar issue with an exception/error being thrown on that 'line' of code where a web application project was trying to compile a website page (one without a designer file).

Comment: Well, I think those two are incongruent, or maybe my previous comment was unclear. If you open a .NET 'Website' by doing 'Open Website' in visual studio, its expecting not to see designer files, right? Only if you open a 'Project' should it show it.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. As you probably suspect, It's indeed a web application

Comment: No worries. I am guessing that the file encoding is standard and not other than Western European 1252? I'm just trying to eliminate any potential gotchas. How about re-creating the files from scratch and copy/pasting the code into notepad then back into the code files?

Comment: Had to resort to recreating the files, but it seems to have done the trick.  I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Your missing @ symbol in your <%@ Page......

Comment: +1, as you are correct. Unfortunately it's just a typo as I'm copying from an air-gapped system. Issue remains.